# Проблема со сборкой в исполняемый файл Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите пожалуйста, не получается установить библиотеку для сборки проекта, выпадает ошибка:
[image]

Comment: Сдается мне, что где-то здесь несовместимость случилась. Попробуй обновить Python до последней версии и pip

Comment: @svmitin, python версии 3.8.1, а pip 19.0.3

Comment: Подозреваю что ругается на кириллицу в пути - "C:\Users\Евгений". Попробуйте создать пользователя латиницей и под ним установить библиотеку.

Comment: А `wheel` установлен вообще? `pip install wheel`, затем повторить установку pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему созданием нового пользователя на компьютере. До этого путь содержал русские символы.